# After navigating vendors not loading NEXT.JS Link

Tags: typescript, next.js

[Here is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Wam3.png) what isn't working. As the title said it's not loading as navbar's responsiveness corrupts.

```
return (
        <Link  key={index} href={'/'+item.id} >     
         <li className="nav-item dropdown position-static active">
          <a className="nav-link" href={item.id} >{item.categoryName}</a> 
         </li>
        </Link>
)
```

code above is how I'm routing now. When I change it to simple HTML5  tag it works as expected.
How to add vendors correctly or proper way to use Links.

```
<script src="http://localhost:3000/vendor/jquery.min.js"  />
<script src="http://localhost:3000/vendor/popper.js/popper.min.js"  />
<script src="http://localhost:3000/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"  />
<script src="http://localhost:3000/vendor/mega-menu/assets/js/custom.js"  />
<script src="http://localhost:3000/vendor/aos-next/dist/aos.js"  />
<script src="http://localhost:3000/vendor/jquery.appear.js"  />
<script src="http://localhost:3000/vendor/jquery.countTo.js"/>
<script src="http://localhost:3000/vendor/mixitup-3/mixitup.min.js"/>
<script src="http://localhost:3000/js/theme.js" />
```

this is how I'm importing vendors.

In Navbar component Navigation links are dynamic so I'm using useEffect to fetch data.

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchCategory().then(res => {
      setCategory(res);
    })
    console.log(router.pathname)
  },[router.pathname, id]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set `Link` as the direct parent of `a`, and use `passHref` prop to pass `href` attribute from `Link` to `a`.

```
return (
   <li key={index} className="nav-item dropdown position-static active">
      <Link href={'/'+item.id} passHref> 
         <a className="nav-link">{item.categoryName}</a> 
      </Link>
   </li>
)
```

Comment: Sorry sir it didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Could you share how your UI looks like with and without Link? @OchkoMN

Comment: Ok sir, I added the picture of my navbar. It happens nothing when I click if using Link but it works magically when using <a> tag.